# Why scanf() reads two values when we put spaces after format specifier even we are passing one reference

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int a;
    printf("Enter a value \n");
    scanf("%d ",&a);
    printf("a=%d \n",a);
}
```

In `scanf()` function I put space after the format specifier. When i run this program `scanf()` reads two values from the user and only the first value is assigned to 'a'.

1. Why does `scanf()` read two values when we use spaces **after** format specifier even though we are passing one reference in above program?
2. Why does `scanf()` read one value when we use space **before** format specifier even though we are passing one reference?
3. How will the `scanf()` function work?

Comment: This would help you - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf

Comment: Remove the space after `"%d "`. A space before the format specifier cleans off whitespace characters in the input buffer, but `"%d"` format does that anyway (unlike `"%c"` format).

Comment: @WeatherVane I think it should be "A space after the format specifier.....".

Comment: @SkrewEverything what should? Be specific. I mention a space before and after. You only write half a comment.

Comment: @WeatherVane Sorry! You said correct in the sentence to remove the space after the format specifier but in the second sentence you wrote "A space before the format specifier....". I think it should be "A space after the format specifier...". Am I right or wrong? My english is bad, so I may understood it wrong. Correct me.

Comment: A space *before* the format specifier cleans off any leading whitespace. The space *afterwards* messes it up, which is why it should be removed. But for `" %d"` there is no need of the space before, because `%d` cleans off leading whitespace anyway.

Comment: @WeatherVane Got it.

Comment: Hope my answer here helps! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39161028/error-while-taking-the-input/39171222#39171222

Comment: Hope my answer here helps! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39161028/error-while-taking-the-input/39171222#39171222

Answer (score 0):

First of all you would want to change your `int a;` to a pointer, 2) when you specify a variable to be as `int` it only expect integer number 0-9 and space is a `char` character, 3) i think number would answer this too

Comment: because pointer is made to store address of a value in memory

Comment: @jacky pointer stores address of a variable or address of the allocated memory but not address of a value. And what difference it makes in using pointer and `int` in his code?

Answer (score 0):

Same question has been asked on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/If-I-use-a-space-after-last-format-specifier-in-a-scanf-function-in-C-why-does-it-need-another-input-to-break-the-function)

> A space in a scanf format string matches an arbitrary amount of
>   whitespace in the input.
>
> To match all of that arbitrary amount of input space, it has to see
>   something to terminate the whitespace--i.e., something other than
>   whitespace (and a new-line is whitespace, so it isn't sufficient).

That's why you need to enter second time(which should not be a whitespace to terminate the `scanf()`).

White space includes space, tabs, or newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Hope my answer here helps!

[Error While taking the input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39161028/error-while-taking-the-input/39171222#39171222)

Always avoid using whitespaces or tabspaces in the scanf unless you intend to! which is required in some scenarios.

Why this behaviour of scanf?

scanf uses whitespaces, newlines, tabs as delimiters. It stops taking input as soon as it read these 3 from the keyboard.

Since you are providing whitespace in the scanf, after entering the integer it will now wait either for a newline, whitespace to be entered through the keyboard to match that whitespace of yours and after that it will finish taking it's input from the keyboard.